# Javascript Library that can create detailed CSS-like Reflections:

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a javascript library I can use that can create reflections & where I can make the reflection skew & change the reflection's scale?

I need to be able to show reflections on all major browsers(Safari, Firefox, Chrome & maybe IE) which is why I am trying to find a javascript library because AFAIK Firefox & IE have no CSS way to make a reflection(is that correct?).

Comment: Any chance you can do this server side? Way easier.

Comment: how could this be done server side? Generating images then sending them to the browser?

Comment: Yes, server-side you have much more powerful programming options. Like libraries written for image manipulation instead of javascript which really didn't have images in mind when written. Take for example this php based slideshow one. The reflections are all done server-side. http://finnrudolph.de/ImageFlow (not to mention cached so that you aren't wasting a ton of processing power on image edits)

Answer (score 0):

The [CVI library](http://www.netzgesta.de/reflex/) of Christian Effenberger includes a reflection generation component. I don't know about the skew or scale effects.